# How to get live updates when a change is made in my cloud firstore database?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I'm building a chat using Angular and firebase cloud Firestore.

What I'm trying to achieve is to update a counter in the client side every time any document in the collection 'groups' is updated;

In my client-side app, each time a user sends a message, a new message document is added to the `groups/{group_uid}/messages/` collection.

At the same time, the `groups/{group_uid}.current_index` document field gets incremented by 1.

I have also got `groups/{group_uid}.last_read_index` which is an object of key-value pairs that for each member of the group chat, stores the uid as key and an index as a value;

I'm trying to detect a user's unread messages by checking a user's `last_read_index` against the group's `current_index`.

To do so, in the constructor of the app.component I'm currently doing:

```
constructor(private _auth: AuthService,
          private _chat: ChatService,
          private afDb: AngularFireDatabase) {

 this.afDb.list<any>('groups').valueChanges().subscribe(() => {


    this._chat.getUserGroups().get().then(groups => {
      this.counter = 0;
      groups.docs.forEach(group => {
        const groupData = group.data();
        const groupUnreadMessages = groupData.current_index - groupData.last_read_index[this._auth.currentUserId];
        this.counter = this.counter + groupUnreadMessages;
      });
    });

 });

}
```

Where `this._chat.getUserGroups()` returns a collection of all the groups a user is part of.

The problem I'm having is, when a new message is created in the database, in order to see the counter update its value, I need to refresh the page.

Instead I would like the change to happen in real time, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Is this a problem of your data not being updated real time and/or the gui not being updated real time?

Comment: it's a client side problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Angular, but I have done something similar; just use `addOnChildEventListener`, and in the method `onChildChanged()` you can know when the database is being updated and proceed to do something there. Let's say the messages are being changed, this child listener will be waiting for something to change in the database, it might get some time before it updates, but I think is pretty fast, after that listener is triggered you can proceed to do whatever you want inside `onChildChanged`.

Take a look at [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ChildEventListener).

> onChildChanged(DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChildName) This
>   method is triggered when the data at a child location has changed.

Take a look, this is an example from Java. This is what I have done, just created a method with the database reference inside and the `addOnChildEventListener` with all the methods:

```
  private void checkUpdatedData(){

        mDatabase.child("Users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("Messages").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                //If there is a new message i update the UI or bring some value to the user

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Since this is called in `onCreate()` (the main method that executes an Activity) the listener will be listening all the time for changes, also `onChildAdded()` you can know when new messages are being added to the database.

Answer (score 0):

For angular use [AngularFire2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2). It has **subscribe** property which keeps track of changes happening in Firestore